# Can a class have a discriminatorvalue and a discriminatorcolumn at the same time?

Tags: java, jpa

Suppose I have a superclass Animal.
Given we have two classes Omnivore and Herbivore that extend that class.
Now let the Omnivore also have two classes that extends from Omnivore, Pig and Bear.

Suppose those are all entities that I want to map with JPA.

Let's say Animal has @DiscriminatorColumn, Omnivore and Herbivore @DiscriminatorValue.

Omnivore is also a superclass. Can it have also @DiscriminatorColumn? ( Pig and bear will have @DiscriminatorValue )?

In other words Omnivore has @DiscriminatorValue and @DiscriminatorColumn at the same time.

Is this situation possible?

Comment: A column defines the schema info, a value defines the value to be stored in it. They define different things, hence no reason why you cannot put BOTH in one class